# Java script working in Chrome, Fire Fox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Hi the following java script is working in both Chrome , fire fox and IE except IE 11:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        // DO something
    }
});
```

Only in IE 11 we have this problem, in a windows 8.1 operating system. System : Sony Vaio Duo

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: we are using 1.9.1 version

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle example?

Comment: What part of your code isn't working?

Comment: That I am not quite sure, since it was reported by a client. However it definitely not going inside the if loop I believe.

Comment: Best bet is to set variables with the values from the `scrollTop()` and `height()` calls, and debug it based on that in IE11.

Comment: Is it because he is using a wider version? and that if value check goes less everytime? really a hard guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= parseFloat($(document).height()) - parseFloat($(window).height())) {
    // DO something
  }
});
```

Comment: He shouldn't have to parse those values as they're already floats.

Comment: Added ParseFloat to left and added a +2 , while debugging the righthandside always returned fraction of points higher. Hence the if loop dint work. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >=(parseFloat($(document).height()) - parseFloat($(window).height()))) {
    // DO something
  }
});
```